# Python Twisted How To Set the SSL Method for twisted.web.client.Agent using new IPolicyForHTTPS?

Tags: python, ssl, https, twisted

The Twisted [howto docs for using Agent over SSL](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html#http-over-ssl) suggest using  creating a `ContextFactory`, but the [API docs for t.w.c.Agent](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html) show that the `contextFactory` argument is now supposed to be an object that implements `t.w.i.IPolicyForHTTPS`.  The source code looks like it wraps old ContextFactories to implement the new interface, but it issues a deprecation warning.

How is one supposed to set the SSL method (e.g. SSLv3), using the new interface?

Using the old `ContextFactory`, I can understand where my code can receive a PyOpenSSL `OpenSSL.SSL.Context` and set the SSL method using that object.  Using the new interface, it is not clear to me where my code can set the SSL method.

Comment: Why do you want to support SSLv3?  TLS 1.0 came out in *1999*.

Comment: I don't actually want to support SSLv3-- but there are times when you may want to force a particular version.  Granted, I typically want to force a higher version, but I may want to force a lower/broken version if I want to find out what a server is willing to accept (e.g. when running diagnostics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to set the SSL method (the default is TLS 1.0 or higher), you will need to subclass twisted.web.client.BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS (untested):

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import reactor, ssl
from twisted.web import client

class MyPolicy(client.BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS):
    def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):
        return ssl.optionsForClientTLS(
            hostname.decode("ascii"),
            extraCertificateOptions={'method': SSL.SSLv3_METHOD},
            trustRoot=self._trustRoot
        )

myAgent = client.Agent(reactor, contextFactory=MyPolicy())
```